# Angular Http Client : JSON Object returned from Java Service missing an attribute on client side

Tags: java, json, angular, typescript

I am working on a Java + Angular web app. I have a java web service that returns a json object, here is the log for the data returned on server side:

GET NG-MENU JSON Object:

```json
{
  "status": true,
  "warnStatus": false,
  "isLogout": false,
  "errorMsg": "",
  "warningMsg": "",
  "techMsg": "",
  "rtndata": [],
  "rtndataDtl1": [],
  "rtndataDtl2": [],
  "rtndataDtl3": [],
  "rtndataDtl4": [],
  "rtnData2": [],
  "jsonObject": {
    "map": {
      "nglink": "",
      "icon": "pi pi-fw pi-calendar",
      "id": "2000",
      "label": "Setups",
      "items": {
        "myArrayList": [
          {
            "map": {
              "nglink": "",
              "icon": "",
              "label": "Misc.",
              "items": {
                "myArrayList": [
                  {
                    "map": {
                      "nglink": "/setup/city",
                      "icon": "pi pi-fw pi-home",
                      "label": "Cities",
                      "items": {
                        "myArrayList": []
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Server Side Code snippet:

```java
Gson g = new Gson();
System.out.println("GET NG-MENU JSON Object : "+g.toJson(rtnObj));
return g.toJson(rtnObj);
```

On the client side, I make a HTTP request and get this data, here is the log on the client side:

```
"errorMsg":"""isLogout":"false
    jsonObject":"map":"icon":"pi pi-fw pi-calendar""id":"2000""items":"Array(1)
    0":{
   "label":"Misc.",
   "id":"",
   "icon":"",
   "items":Array(1)
}"length":1[
   [
      "Prototype"
   ]
]:"Array(0)
    label":"Setups"[
   [
      "Prototype"
   ]
]:"Object"[
   [
      "Prototype"
   ]
]:"Object
    rtnData2":[
   
]"rtndata":[
   
]"rtndataDtl1":[
   
]"rtndataDtl2":[
   
]"rtndataDtl3":[
   
]"rtndataDtl4":[
   
]"status":"true
    techMsg":"""warnStatus":"false
    warningMsg":""
```

Client side code snippet:

```typescript
http.post<any>(this.weburldev + "basic/menu2", {
    appID: parentApplication.appID,
    userID: parentApplication.UserID,
  })
  .subscribe((response: any) => {
    // handle successful response here
    console.log(
      "Response from app menu service : " + this.weburldev + "basic/menu"
    );
    console.log(response);
  });
```

**Edit**

The response from response tab in developer tools :

```json
{
  "status": true,
  "warnStatus": false,
  "isLogout": false,
  "errorMsg": "",
  "warningMsg": "",
  "techMsg": "",
  "rtndata": [],
  "rtndataDtl1": [],
  "rtndataDtl2": [],
  "rtndataDtl3": [],
  "rtndataDtl4": [],
  "rtnData2": [],
  "jsonObject": {
    "map": {
      "icon": "pi pi-fw pi-calendar",
      "rl": "",
      "id": "2000",
      "label": "Setups",
      "items": {
        "myArrayList": [
          {
            "map": {
              "icon": "",
              "rl": "",
              "label": "Misc.",
              "items": {
                "myArrayList": [
                  {
                    "map": {
                      "icon": "pi pi-fw pi-home",
                      "rl": "/setup/city",
                      "label": "Cities",
                      "items": {
                        "myArrayList": []
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The response in the Network>Response Tab shows the nglink(rl) field but the response object of HTTP request doesnot.
The response on the client side is missing the "nglink" attribute for all menuitems. I have been debugging this for hours but I cannot understand what is causing this, any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

If any other information can help improve the question please let me know as well! Thanks!

Comment: have you try your post request to Postman? 
In order to see that the response is correct?

Comment: It would be nice if you can format the response JSON for better readability.

Comment: @chameerar done in the edit, thanks!

Comment: Can you also provide JSON of the response object from the client? You can get it by from dev tools, by right clicking on the response and copying it

Comment: @mat.hudak thanks for the tip, I've added the response in an edit. The response tab in developer tools shows the nglink field but the response object of the HTTP request doesn't.

Comment: @KostasNitaf Hi thanks, I did try on Postman after your suggestion. I found out that the nglink attribute is visible on postman and in the response in network tab but is missing in the response from httpcclient

Comment: Do you have some HTTP interceptor implemented which can be causing that?

Comment: @mat.hudak not sure but I am just using the `{ HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http' `

Comment: @Shahzaib - please make a console log to your parentApplication.appID,
and  parentApplication.UserID, before sending the request and see if you have the right values!

Comment: @KostasNitaf already did that on both the client and server side. The values are correct and the server side is sending the correct response. I can also see the correct response on Postman and in the networks tab of developer tools in the browser. It's the response from the HttpClient in angular that is missing one attribute.

Comment: @Shahzaib, maybe that property is missing on that side. Check for spelling and casing also. At times it gets very tricky.